# Javascript Promise Question, why does Chain not work

Tags: javascript, promise

So this works

```js
new Promise(res => {
  console.log("1")
  res(res);
}).then(res => {
  console.log("2")
}).then(res => {
  console.log("3")
})
```

But if I exclude the res(res), it will not chain.  But it chains fine afterwards without any additional res().

Why is that, why does the first block matter if it has that res() and the subsequent blocks don't need it in order to chain onwards ?

Thanks.

Comment: The promise constructor gets a callback called the executor. If you don't resolve the promise in the executor, the promise never resolves by itself.

Comment: `new Promise.resolved().then(`

Comment: `res` is the executor parameter which controls the resolution of the promise. calling `res(someValue)` resovles the promise and `someValue` is available in the subsequent `.then` handler. `.then` handlers do not have the same type of control and instead use the handler's return value to resolve a new value. `res(res)` is an odd thing to write since as it resolves the `res` control function itself. promises can only be resolved (or rejected) once, so calling `res` multiple times would not have the effect you maybe are expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It chains just fine without the call to `res()` in that the succeeding `.then()` handlers are chained onto the original promise.

But, the original promise will never be resolved if you don't execute `res(someValue)` so therefore, it will never call your `.then()` handlers.  At some point, you have to resolve the original promise at the start of the chain if you want any of the `.then()` handlers to get called.  Until you call `res(someValue)`, you have a promise chain where the head of the chain is sitting in the `pending` state waiting to be resolved or rejected so it can then run the rest of the chain.

> But if I exclude the res(res), it will not chain. But it chains fine afterwards without any additional res().

The original promise has to be resolved before the first `.then()` handler will get called.  From then on, just returning from a `.then()` handler resolves the next promise in the chain - you no longer have to manually resolve it.

From within a `.then()` handler, you can trigger different outcomes three different ways:

1. **Return from the `.then()` handler.**  This resolves that chained promise and triggers its `.then()` handlers to get called.  If you return a value, that value becomes the new resolved value of this part of the chain.  If you don't return a value or there's an implicit return, then the resolved value is `undefined`.
2. **Throw an exception from within the `.then()` handler.**  This will be automatically caught by  the promise infrastructure and will cause this promise in the promise chain to reject - trigger any `.catch()` handler to get called.
3. **Return a promise from the `.then()` handler.**  This causes the current promise in the chain to track this new promise and it will resolve or reject based on what the newly returned promise does.

---

Also, a given promise can only be resolved or rejected once.  It's a one-way state machine.  Once it has been resolved or rejected, it's state is fixed and can not be changed again.  So, you would only ever call `res(someValue)` once.  Attempting to call it more than once just does nothing as the promise has already been changed to the `fulfilled` state and can no longer be changed.

FYI, the three states of a promise are `pending`, `fulfilled` and `rejected`.  When you call `res(someValue)`, you change the state of the original promise in your chain from `pending` to `fulfilled` and the internals of the promise will then call its `.then()` handlers on the next tick.

Something that people often don't realize is that each call to `.then()` creates and returns a new promise that is linked to the earlier promise chain.  So, the code in your question actually creates 3 promises, one from `new Promise()` and two from the two calls to `.then()`.  These subsequent promises from calls to `.then()` get resolved or rejected only when the parent promise gets resolved or rejected and the `.then()` or `.catch()` handler gets called and then there's a return value from that `.then()` or `.catch()` handler.  Those return values from those handlers determine what happens next in the chain.